# Android MotionLayout, how can I change it's height?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-motionlayout, material3, android-compose-layout

How can I change the height of my motionLayout, when swiping.
With my current code, I can only translate a view (but then I will remain with grey there)
I need to modify it's size, as this header is used in multiple fragments, including some PreferenceCompat, and hence I want it to be wrap content to add non compose views under it.

Currently if I swipe up, it takes my view up -> but keeps a greyed out thing

[image]

I have this motionLayout:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class)
@Composable
fun AddressableMotionLayout(
    item: XCCAddressableReference,
    listener: AddressableInfoContentAdapter.AddressableClickListener?,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val motionScene = remember {
        context.resources
            .openRawResource(R.raw.motion_scene)
            .readBytes()
            .decodeToString()
    }
    val motionState = rememberMotionLayoutState()
    val corners = 10f - ((motionState.currentProgress * 10)).coerceAtMost(10f)

    MotionLayout(
        motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionScene),
        motionLayoutState = motionState,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.LightGray)
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId("header")
                .background(colorResource(id = R.color.xelionMainColor))
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = corners, topEnd = corners))
                .layoutId("contentBg")
        )

        Button(
            onClick = {

            },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(contentColor = Color.White),
            modifier = Modifier.layoutId("menu"), contentPadding = PaddingValues(4.dp),
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                contentDescription = ""
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This is my motion_scene:

```
{
 ConstraintSets: {
 start: {
  header: {
    width: 'parent',
    height: 250,
    top: ['parent', 'top', 0],
    start: ['parent', 'start', 0],
    end: ['parent', 'end', 0],
    translationY: 0,
    alpha: 1
  },
  contentBg: {
    width: 'spread',
    height: 0,
    start: ['parent', 'start',16],
    end: ['parent', 'end',16],
    top: ['parent','top', 200],
    bottom: ['parent','bottom'],
  },
  menu: {
    width: 38,
    height: 38,
    start: ['parent', 'start', 16],
    top: ['parent', 'top', 16],
  },
},
end: {
  header: {
    width: 'parent',
    height: 250,
    top: ['parent', 'top', 0],
    start: ['parent', 'start', 0],
    end: ['parent', 'end', 0],
    translationY: -250,
    alpha: 1,
  },
  contentBg: {
    width: 'spread',
    height: 0,
    start: ['parent', 'start'],
    end: ['parent', 'end'],
    top: ['parent','top'],
    bottom: ['parent','bottom'],
  },
  menu: {
    width: 38,
    height: 38,
    start: ['parent', 'start', 16],
    top: ['parent', 'top', 16],
  },
},
 },
 Transitions: {
default: {
  from: 'start',
  to: 'end',
  onSwipe: {
    anchor: 'contentBg',
    direction: 'up',
    side: 'top',
  },
  }
  }

 }
```

Comment: did you figure it out yet?